# Where is Request.AcceptTypes.Contains in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I see many references to this piece of code on the internets:

```
if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains ...
```

But for the life of me, I cannot find the namespace where this method exists.

We are using MVC4 WebApi, is this MVC3-specific?. Please, before I pull out the rest of my hair.

EDIT:

Going with @Styxxyless answer, this is what I get (no AcceptTypes). I know I am missing something obvious, but what is it?

[image]

Also, I have a reference to System.Web in my project.

Comment: Type in `Request.AcceptTypes`, not `System.Web.HttpRequest`.  `System.Web.HttpRequest` is the actual class, not the actual Request object, so you aren't going to see instance methods/properties on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **MVC**, the code is as follows:

```
Request.AcceptTypes.Contains([MIME type]);
```

For **Web API**, the functionality is achieved using the following code:

```
this.Request.Headers.Accept.Contains(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue([MIME type]))
```

***or***

```
this.Request.Headers.GetValues("Accept").Contains([MIME type])
```

An example of a MIME type is: `"image/jpeg"`

Answer (score 2):

[System.Web.HttpRequest.AcceptTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.accepttypes.aspx)

```
public string[] AcceptTypes { get; }
```

> Gets a string array of client-supported MIME accept types.

And the `Contains()` method is just the basic [`IEnumerable.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not see `AcceptTypes` there. I have updated my answer with a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

It's (`.Contains`) a method from `IEnumerable`, which `Array` implements.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.100).aspx

Edit:

If you look at the definition for `Controller` (which your controller class derived from), we have this:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets the System.Web.HttpRequestBase object for the current HTTP request.
//
// Returns:
//     The request object.
public HttpRequestBase Request { get; }
```

So that's why the code you see online is using `Request.AcceptTypes`, and not `System.Web.HttpRequest`.  The name of the property is `Request`, but it returns an `HttpRequestBase`.  Now if the `System.Web.HttpRequest` class had a static property named `AcceptTypes`, you would be able to access it via `System.Web.HttpRequest.AcceptTypes`.

Sorry about all the confusion!

Implementation:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("image/jpeg"))
    {
        // Do something.
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: My questions is more about `AcceptTypes`, not `Contains`.

Comment: The very first result in Google for `Request.AcceptTypes` is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.accepttypes(v=vs.100).aspx....

Comment: Not sure the relevance of that last comment.

Comment: It's the documentation for Request.AcceptTypes, which is what you were asking about.

Comment: I hope I am not coming across as too aggressive, but have you actually tried this in code, or are you simply doing Google searches without checking your answers? Please see my **answer** to understand why I am asking this.

Comment: Look at the link you posted again.  No where in there is it saying you accessed via `System.Web.HttpRequest.AcceptTypes`.  Please look at the example code on the MSDN page you linked in your answer, you'll see they access if via `Request.AcceptTypes`.

Comment: The point of my answer is that the documentation is evidently wrong. Unless you have implemented it successfully.....

Comment: should we go to chat? It looks like you were successful? I would love to get to the bottom of this :)

Comment: No need at all for chat.  Look at the implementation code I put in my answer, or look at the implementation Microsoft has on the page you have referenced.  My code compiles and runs.

Comment: Are you on .NET 4.5, inside of WebAPI or MVC. I think that might be the delta.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17135/discussion-between-gromer-and-shai-cohen)

Comment: Unfortunately, I just found out that my company blocks chat.stackoverflow. I cannot express how frustrated I am.

Comment: Looks like it is a MVC vs Web API issue after all. Check out my answer if you are interested. Thanks again.